# Windows Phone 7 application trial when publishing to the marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I publish a WP7 app. to the marketplace do I have to code something for the trial version of the app. ? I've seen that each app. in the marketplace that isn't free has a trial version. Does MS and the marketplace handle this or I should deliver a trial version of the app too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decide what functionality is available in the trial version, but the marketplace manages most of the process for you.

See the MSDN ["Creating Trial Applications"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967554%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) pages for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can add check for trial code to your app using:

```
        Microsoft.Phone.Marketplace.LicenseInformation license = new Microsoft.Phone.Marketplace.LicenseInformation();
        var isTrial = license.IsTrial();
```

Note - Microsoft ask you to not call this frequently - so best to call it once and cache the result.

You can then use the isTrial variable to turn features on/off.

When you can want to send your users back to the Marketplace for the full purchase you can then use:

```
    var task = new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.MarketplaceDetailTask();
    task.Show();
```

Then the only remaining thing to do is to check the "Trial supported" checkbox when you upload to the Marketplace.

Also some warnings

- the current AppHub reporting only gives limited feedback on Trial vs Full purchasing - e.g. it's impossible to work out how many people have upgraded. So it might be worth adding your own analytics for this type of thing.
- there have been some developers who have suggested that providing Trial apps can lead to poor ratings - since Trial users can slam the Trial-limited functionality - and their reviews are shown in amongst the full user reviews.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IsTrial to implement trial only features.

[See here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2010/10/18/enabling-your-wp7-application-to-be-installed-in-trial-mode.aspx)